# Unresolved external symbol

Tags: dllimport, dllexport

I have two WIN32 DLL projects in the solution, main.dll should call a function in mgn.dll.

mgn.dll has mgn.h header file:

```
#ifdef MGN_EXPORTS
#define MGN_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MGN_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" bool MGN_API AttachMGN(void);
```

and mgn.cpp source file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "mgn.h"

MGN_API bool AttachMGN(void)
{
...
}
```

main.dll calls AttachMGN function from one of the source file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "..\mgn\mgn.h"

bool CreateClient()
{
    return ::AttachMGN();
}
```

mgn.dll compiles successfully. main.dll doesn't show any errors in VS text editor, I can navigate using "Go To Definition" function. However during build I get the error:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__AttachMGN referenced in function "bool __cdecl CreateClient(void)" (?CreateClient@@AW4XZ)

Both DLLs compile into the same folder. DependencyWalker shows the function AttachMGN as exported. Main project has a dependency set to Mgn project, if that matters.

I believe that I simply have overlooked something....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably just forgot to add MGN.lib to your link arguments for main.dll

Comment: how to do that from VS environment? :8 sorry, this is my first win32 project.

Comment: Just checked and main.dll has the value %(AdditionalDependencies) in the Additional Dependencies field in the Linker->Input section. And main.dll has  has a dependency set to mgn.dll

Comment: Add mgn as a reference to main, it's on the same menu that you use to set it as a dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `mgn.lib` linked with the `main`? By the sound of it, it looks as if `main` cannot find the lib file to link against the DLL.