# Unresolved external symbol (LNK2019)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, linker

I have the following files:
interface.h

```
class Interface
{
  ...
};

Interface* CreateInterface();
```

impl.h

```
#include "interface.h"

class Impl: public Interface
{
  ...
};
```

impl.cpp

```
#include "impl.h"

SomeInterface* CreateInterface()
{
  return new Impl;
}
...
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Interface.h"
int main()
{
  CreateInterface();
}
```

Originally my project looked liked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2481138/279982). But for testing purposes all files are in the same project now.
When compiling I get LNK2019 error saying CreateInterface is unresolved. I'm using VS 2008 I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: Are you sure `impl.cpp` gets compiled? Are you sure you didn't misspell the function name?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore There's no misspelling. As for making sure it's being compiled, how can I do that? All I know if I place a file in source files section of my solution it should be compiled automatically.

Comment: How about adding some dummy code that shouldn't compile in the file. Just place a line `this shouldn't compile;` in the source. If there's no error, the it doesn't get compiled.

Comment: Getting error, so it's being compiled.

Comment: One thing came to mind: is `main.cpp` including the *correct* `interface.h`? In the full LNK2019 error, does the signature and qualification of `CreateInterface` for which the linker is looking match the signature and qualification in `impl.cpp`?

Comment: Found it! the `CreateInterface` was inside a namespace in actual code, and I had forgotten to explicitly state that in `impl.cpp` definition of it. Should've written `Somenamespace::CreateInterface() {...}`

Answer (score 2):

Is it your intention to have multiple `CreateInterface()` declarations?

**Interface.h**

```
Interface* CreateInterface();
```

**Impl.cpp**

```
SomeInterface* CreateInterface()
```

Only one of these (the latter) appears to be actually implemented. You have a name ambiguity and it appears the compiler is choosing the wrong one (most likely because it has no clue the other even exists).

Define `CreateInterface()` in impl.cpp with the *identical* parameter list and return type as the prototype in Interface.h. I would normally not condone such a beastly design, but it appears that is what you want.

**Impl.cpp**

```
Interface* CreateInterface() // note the return type
{
    return new Impl;
}
```

Honestly I can't believe this even compiles, considering you're only difference between the two (the declaration in Interface.h and the implementation in Impl.cpp) is a return type difference, and the compiler should puke all over that, so there is likely something you're still not showing us.

Comment: That was a typo, but nice job spotting it :)

Answer (score 0):

The linker is telling you that it knows that `CreateInterface` exists and is a function, but it cannot find the actual function itself. So I suspect that you are not including impl.cpp in your project, and it's not getting compiled.